# Adding more if statements to my current module in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have already working code, but it only works for one person. I need to be able to have many peoples data moved from one sheet to another

```
Sub button()

With Worksheets("three").Range("G1")

    If .Value = "sconlon@iadvancenow.com" Then

     Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C3") = .Offset(0, 1).Value

     Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D3") = .Offset(0, 2).Value

     End If

With Worksheets("three").Range("G1")

    If .Value = "kedwards@iadvancenow.com" Then

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C4") = .Offset(0, 1).Value

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D4") = .Offset(0, 2).Value

    End If

End With 

End Sub
```

I only get the results from the first person

Comment: If you are always looking at different possible value for one cell, you may want to look into `Select Case`

Answer (score 1):

Your current code should fail to compile with a `Compile error: Expected End With`. You only need 1 `With` statement for what you're trying to do. Additionally, utilize `If/ElseIf` in this scenario:

```
Sub button()

    With Worksheets("three").Range("G1")

        If .Value = "sconlon@iadvancenow.com" Then

            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C3") = .Offset(0, 1).Value
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D3") = .Offset(0, 2).Value

        ElseIf .Value = "kedwards@iadvancenow.com" Then

            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C4") = .Offset(0, 1).Value
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D4") = .Offset(0, 2).Value

        Else

            'Add whatever else you need - or maybe some more ElseIfs!

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

However, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish - right now you're only looking at cell `G1` - how is your data setup? You'd have to include more details for us to help you.